# Finding similar names better than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, fuzzy-search

Say I've got a list of names. Unfortunately, there are some duplicates, but it isn't obvious which of those are duplicates.

```
Tom Riddle
Tom M. Riddle
tom riddle
Tom Riddle, PhD.
```

I'm thinking of using **Levenshtein distance**, and there are definitely other algorithms that do come to mind to compare 2 names at a time.

But in a list of names, regardless of the string distance algorithm, I'll always end up generating a grid of comparison outputs (`n^2`).

How can I avoid the `O(n^2)` situation?

Comment: Inverted index is a good solution. But for western names, maybe simply split by non-letter chars (e.g space) is enough, then calculate the similarity of 2 names on fly, just like what Lucene does, `Elasticsearch` and `Solr` already provide easy to use solution to such requirement.

Comment: Do you want "Thomas Riddle" and "Tomas Riddle" to match "Tom Riddle"? And what about "Riddle, Tom"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction

What you want to do is known as [Fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). Let me guide you through the topic.

First, setup an **inverted index** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)) of **n-grams** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)). That is, split a word like `"hello"` into, for example `3`-grams:

```
"$$h", "$he", "hel", "ell", "llo", "lo$", "o$$"
```

And have a map which maps every *n-gram* to a list of words that contain it:

```
"$$h" -> ["hello", "helloworld", "hi", "huhu", "hey"]
"$he" -> ["hello", "helloworld", "hey"]
...
"llo" -> ["hello", "helloworld", "llowaddup", "allo"]
...
```

All words in your database are now indexed by their n-grams. This is why it is called **inverted** index.

The idea is, given a query, to compute how many n-grams the query has in common with all words in your database. This can be computed fast. After that you can use this to skip computation of the expensive edit distance for a huge set of records. Which **dramatically** increases the speed. It is the standard approach that all search engines use (more or less).

Let me first explain the general approach by the example of an *exact match*. After that we will slightly modify it and get to the fuzzy matching.

---

### Exact match

At query time, compute the *n-gram*s of your query, fetch the lists and compute the intersection.

Like if you get `"hello"` you compute the grams and get:

```
"$$h", "$he", "hel", "ell", "llo", "lo$", "o$$"
```

You fetch all lists for all of those *n-gram*s:

```
List result;
foreach (String nGram) in (query.getNGrams()) {
    List words = map.get(nGram);
    result = result.intersect(words);
}
```

The intersection contains all words which match exactly those grams, this is `"hello"` only.

Note that an exact match can be computed faster by using hashing, like a `HashSet`.

---

### Fuzzy match

Instead of intersecting the lists, **merge** them. In order to merge efficiently you should use any [k-way merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), it requires the list of words in your inverted index to be **sorted** prior though, so make sure to sort it at construction.

You now get a list of all words that have at least one *n-gram* in common with the query.

We already greatly reduced the set of possible records. But we can do even better. Maintain, for each word, the amount of how many *n-gram*s it has in common with the query. You can easily do that **while merging** the lists.

Consider the following threshold:

```
max(|x|, |y|) - 1 - (delta - 1) * n
```

where `x` is your query, `y` the word candidate you are comparing against. `n` is the value for the *n-grams* you have used, `3` if `3-gram` for example. `delta` is the value of how many mistakes you allow.

If the count is **below** that value, you directly know that the edit distance is

```
ED(x, y) > delta
```

So you only need to consider words with a count more than the above threshold. Only for those words you compute the edit distance `ED(x, y)`.

By that we extremely reduced the set of possible candidates and only compute the expensive edit distance on a small amount of records.

---

### Example

Suppose you get the query `"hilari"`. Let's use `3-gram`s. We get

```
"$$h", "$hi", "hil", "ila", "lar", "ari", "ri$", "i$$"
```

We search through our inverted index, merge lists of words that have those grams in common and get `"hillary"`, `"haemophilia"`, `"solar"`. Together with those words we counted how many grams they have in common:

```
"hillary"      -> 4 ("$$h", "hi", "hil", "lar")
"haemophilia"  -> 2 ("$$h", "hil")
"solar"        -> 1 ("lar")
```

Check each entry against the threshold. Let `delta` be `2`. We get:

```
4 >= max(|"hilari"|, |"hillary"|) - 4     = 3
2 <  max(|"hilari"|, |"haemophilia"|) - 4 = 6
1 <  max(|"hilari"|, |"solar"|) - 4       = 2
```

Only `"hillary"` is above the threshold, discard the rest. Compute the edit distance for all remaining records:

```
ED("hilari", "hillary") = 2
```

Which is not beyond `delta = 2`, so we accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be hard. Accept that you will make mistakes and don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Begin by removing honorifics (Mr, Mrs, Sir, Dr, PhD, Jr, Sr,). Remove common first names (based on a list of first names) and initials and convert all characters to upper case. Create a *signature* for whatever is left — use Soundex or something similar, or simply remove all vowels and doubled consonants. Sort by signature to bring like names together, then run the full compare only on names with the same signature. That reduces the time complexity to O(*n* log *n*) for the sorting plus a little O(*k*²) for each set of *k* signatures.

Comment: "create a signature"? Yes - that is the whole problem. The rest is easy in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have approached this as an abstract string problem. If that's what you're after then I think they give good advice. I'm going to assume that you would like to use specific knowledge of how names work, so that, for instance, "Mr. Thomas Riddle, Esq" and "Riddle, Tom" would match "Tom Riddle", but "Tom Griddle" wouldn't.

In general with this kind of problem you define some kind of canonicalization function and look for terms that canonicalize to the same thing. In this case, it seems like your canonical representation of a name ought to include a lower-case version of first and last name, stripped of any titles, and "de-nicknamed" using a nickname-to-formal-name mapping (assuming you want "Tom" and "Thomas" to match). This function would produce "Tom Riddle" -> `{first: "tom", last: "riddle"}`, "Riddle, Tom" -> `{first: "tom", last: "riddle"}`, "Tom Riddle, Esq" -> `{first: "tom", last: "riddle"}`, and so on, but "Tom Griddle" -> `{first: "tom", last: "griddle"}`.

Once you have a name-canonicalization function, you can create a map (e.g. hashmap or BST) that associates canonical names to a list of uncanonicalized names. For each uncanonicalized name, find the list corresponding to its canonical form in the map and insert it there. Once you're done, all the lists with more than one element are your duplicates.